# Difference between asp.net label text elements and ordnary text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a doubt

What is the Different between  these below type of  labels text declarations ?

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbl2" **Text="Name"** runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and

```
 <asp:Label ID="lbl2"  runat="server"**>Name</**asp:Label>
```

I have straightly providing the text in text property `Text="Name"` and providing the text on center of the label field  `> Name </`

I have some more labels on my gridview controls , I want to get the label text value while  edit the grid, I am using  find control to get the label values

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Label xx = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbl2") as Label;
        Label yy = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbl2") as Label;
        txtName.Text = xx.Text;
        txtAge.Text = yy.Text;
    }
```

Here is my gridview code

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" Text='<%#  Eval("StudentName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

It's working fine, if I put the Eval value in label Text property  , But if i providing the eval values in center of the label, like ( `<asp:Label ID="lbl1"  runat="server"><%#  Eval("StudentName") %></asp:Label>`)  then find control didn't  return the value ,It's returning empty ("") . Why ?

**Edit:**

> But if I set the label text in outside of gridview  , both of way's are working good(lblid.text give correct if set the text in that two way ) ! only i got the problem in label inside of gridview !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is the difference between this label text type ?

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl2" **Text="Name"** runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

will create a `Label` control  which `Text` property will have the value "Name"

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl2"  runat="server"**>Name</**asp:Label>
```

will create a `Label` control

- with `Text` property having the value `String.Empty`
- with a `Literal` child control which `Text` property value will be "Name"

be aware that using both behaviors (setting `Text` property and having content) at the same time might lead to unexpected behavior : see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text.aspx

> **Note** : Setting the Text property will clear any other controls
>   contained in the Label control.

So I think the problem is that when you write :

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl2"  runat="server"**><%#  Eval("StudentName") %></**asp:Label>
```

then

```
Label xx = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbl2") as Label;
txtName.Text = xx.Text;
```

You are trying to access value of a child Literal control which has not yet been DataBound

Not sure it would work or make a difference, but you may try :

```
Label xx = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbl2") as Label;
xx.Controls[0].DataBind();
txtName.Text = xx.Text;
```

Anyway, by now you should have figured that you'd better use the Text property of your Label and not the implicit Text Literal

Comment: But if I set the label text in outside of gridview , both of way's are  working good(lblid.text give correct ) ! only i got the problem in label inside of gridview !

Comment: Hello , My guess is correct ? Please see my answer ? that's it the chance for that bug ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran outside of GridView, you have to replace <%#'s with <%='s changing the semantics (and the moment) the code is evaluated (and the values set) in the page lifecycle. In GridView or not, the literal is added as a ParsedSubObject (which also changes the behaviour of the Text Property) If you have the opportunity, have a look at the Label class source code.

Comment: I can't change # to = , Because if i used # only get the values from gridview datasource , Other wise it's show only ordinary text like <%=Eval("xx") %>

Comment: Sorry : i got a error `Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.` and i saw the line on run time with using break point'It's got empty value only ,when i used the values in center of the label open and close tag

Answer (score 2):

the first to labels will give you spans. no much difference it's more what you prefer
out put in the html:

```
< span id="MainContent_lbl2" >Name< /span >

< span id="MainContent_Label1" >Name< /span >
```

when you write your Eval outside the label you still need to add the ' ' (single quotation) try it and if it didn't work try the  " " double qoutation. I hope I could give you some insight on your question :)

Comment: Hello , My guess is correct ? Please see my answer ? that's it the chance for that bug ?

Answer (score 2):

`<asp:Label ID="lbl2" **Text="Name"** runat="server"></asp:Label>`

I am not sure but this will render the asp label as `<label>` and the text part will be rendered as the `InnerText` of this label where other one

`<asp:Label ID="lbl2"  runat="server"**>Name</**asp:Label>` this will render the Name  as the `InnerHtml` of the `<label>` tab

Comment: You are completely wrong. `<asp:Label` renders as span. See the other answer by [photowalker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2818434/photowalker).

Comment: Hello , My guess is correct ? Please see my answer ? that's it the chance for that bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a answer. ( correct me if I am wrong)

My code behind have two class

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Manually all page controls are defined by my Home class

So the ordinary label gave correct and both type of text value

But my below line was create new label by using `system.Ui.Page` class ,

```
Label yy = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lbl2") as Label;
```

now this find-control get only the label properties value `Text="xx"`  is property of the label so it's get the values , but Name this value is not stored in the any label properties , So we can't get it .

(it's my guess only )

and also i guess another one reason (It's just a joke )

> this client side **`<label>Text</label>`** control have open and closed tag , But server side **`Label`** control have not any open and closed tag, So this reason for i can't get the label value [image]

Comment: +1 for  `now this find-control get only the label properties value Text="xx" is property of the label so it's get the values , but Name this value is not stored in the any label properties , So we can't get it .`

Answer (score 1):

asp:Label controls are rendered as spans, not as html label elements. Use Text property if you need to access the value on the server side. Use id.innerHTML if you need to retrieve the value on the client side using javascript.